# Simping {on/in/for}?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Pretty straight forward question. Which of the following sentences is/are "correct"?

- They are simping **on** Korean players
- They are simping **in** Korean players
- They are simping **for** Korean players

What I want to express is that a group of people feeling extreme sympathy for Korean players in a online international game. I've always used **for** but I see a lot of people writing almost the same sentence using mostly **on** and rarely **in**

Answer (score 2):

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/simp) uses "for" in their example:

> I can't stand to see you simp for someone who gives you the bare minimum.

A similar word that uses "for" as the preposition is "pine" -- if you long for someone painfully, you're said to pine for them.

I don't see how "in" could possibly be right, there's no sense of "in" that expresses this kind of relationship.

"on" is possible, because we sometimes use that with other ways we act towards other people, such as "dote on" and "have pity on".

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary uses  both “for” and “over” in its examples. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simp#

Comment: Problem is that the dictionaries don't declare that *simp* is a shortening of *sympathy* like *suss* is a shortening of *suspicious*.   The OP reads like *carry water for* (also "for") but the dictionaries say that *simp* is like self-abasing submission.

Comment: I think it may be analogous to "pine", as in "you pine for someone". @stevesliva

Comment: "Over" would work by analogy with verbs like "moon" or "obsess", but it seems a bit less active and focused than "simping for" someone.

Comment: Yeah. There's no simple rule about which preposition goes with each verb, they're very ideosyncratic.